# I'm Trying to create a Minecraft Addon with a mob that heals the player

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-modding

I'm working on creating a Minecraft Bedrock Addon that includes an entity that heals the player that tamed it if they are low on health.

I'm having trouble getting this to work. So far I have the following snippets of code in my behavior file.

```
"explore:active_healing": {
            "minecraft:area_effect_cloud": {
                "add_effects": [
                  {
                    "effect": "minecraft:regeneration",
                    "duration": 100,
                    "amplifier": 1,
                    "visible": true
                  }
                ],
                "duration": 20, 
                "radius": 10,
                "particle": "minecraft:spell_emitter"
              }
        }
```

That code is supposed to create a healing field around the mob.
I also have this code to create a custom behavior that activates the healing field.

```
"minecraft:behavior.activate_healing_aura": {
            "priority": 1,
            "filters": {
              "all_of": [
                {
                  "test": "is_family",
                  "subject": "other",
                  "value": "player"
                },
                {
                  "test": "is_owner",
                  "subject": "other",
                  "value": true
                },
                {
                  "test": "health",
                  "subject": "other",
                  "value": 10,
                  "operator": "<"
                }
              ]
            },
            "trigger": {
              "event": "minecraft:entity_tick",
              "target": "self"
            },
            "add": {
              "component_groups": ["explore:active_healing"]
            }
          }
```

I have another piece that does the opposite in order to deactivate the healing when the player has more than 15 health.

At the moment, the entity is not healing the player at all. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.